# Projection of a function $f\in L^1(\Omega)$ onto a finite dimensional subspace

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

Suppose $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a domain such that $|\Omega|<\infty$, $f\in L^1(\Omega)$. Let $Y= \text{span}\{g_1,\dots, g_k\}$.

> Is there a characterization of the set of *projections* of $f$ onto $Y$, i.e. the set $M$ of all $g\in Y$ such that
>   $$
> \int_\Omega |f(x) - g(x)|dx = \inf_{h\in Y} \int_\Omega |f(x) - h(x)|dx,
> $$
>   or, equivalently, $M = \text{argmin} \{ \int_\Omega |f(x) - g(x)|dx : g \in Y\}$?

Similar problem in $L^2$ (minimizing $\int_\Omega |f(x) - g(x)|^2 dx$) is very easy to solve since we have inner product there. However, as $L^1$ norm is not strictly convex, our set $M$ need to contain a unique element in general.

The solution to the $1$-dimensional case $Y = \text{span}\{1\}$ is well known, i.e. $g=c$ where $c\in \Bbb R$ is any median of $f$. Is there a complete treatment of this kind of problem anywhere?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have the same property: for every $g'\in Y$, the sets where $(f-g)g'> 0$ and $(f-g)g'<0$ have measure at most $\frac12|\Omega|$ but I'm not sure if that can be called a "characterization": it is not easy to verify except in the most trivial cases. What are you really after?

Comment: @fedja Knowing general properties of $M$ would be a starter, e.g. if it is closed, convex, $G_\delta$ etc. I do agree that the property you mentioned seems hard to verify. Regardless, I still find it quite interesting. Do you perhaps have a reference to that or something similar that I could read?

Comment: Closed and convex are (almost) obvious properties. The property I mentioned follows from looking at what happens if you add $g'$ to $g$ (assuming that everything is real valued). As I said, what may be useful to you depends on what you really want.

Comment: @fedja What I'm looking for is a somewhat effective way to actually compute the projection like how we compute $L^2$ projection. Computing need not mean an explicit formula. A fixed point iteration or a method to find a sequence that converges to a solution would be fine.

Comment: OK, that is something to think of (or to search in the literature). :-)

Comment: I talked to our numerical analysis professor and he said something about  alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM). You may want to look it up and see if it gives you anything useful. As of now, I'd rather wait for what MO numerical experts say before thinking of how I would approach the problem myself...

Comment: @fedja Thank you so much, I'd definitely take a look at the method. I thought about this problem this morning when I read about some inequality involving median and $l^1$ norm and wanted to know if it generalized. Turns out to be more interesting than I thought.

Comment: Are you primarily interested in an answer for a specific choice of $g_1,\dots,g_k$, or in full generality? I guess you'd have said if it was the former, but no harm in asking!

Comment: @DCM I'd say generally. I don't have a specific problem that I want to solve but this just seems like an interesting question to me.